# Mysql replication does not work with different db engines?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

We are replicating 1db to other clusters but It is not replicating all the tables.
I do not know what is the issue. It always shows replication status synchronized.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Currently replication works only with the InnoDB storage engine. Any writes to tables of other types, including system (mysql.*) tables are not replicated (this limitation excludes DDL statements such as CREATE USER, which implicitly modify the mysql.* tables — those are replicated). There is however experimental support for MyISAM - see the wsrep_replicate_myisam system variable)

Reference [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/).

If you are using innodb as default db engine then use innodb with all tables.

It is the possible cause:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You can fix in this way. Run above on master server.

Comment: That only applies to the Tungsten replicator (not asynch repl) and the OP never said what kind of replication the question relates to.